# How to create IAM user with full access to AWS via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I lost access to my AWS account due to loss of my phone with Authenticator app, but I still have access to console. The problem is that somehow the phone number in my account was incorrect and I can't restore access automatically. Support said there is a typo in number and if I have another user with full access, I will be able to change it to correct number and proceed to restore my account via MFA troubleshooting form.

So, the question is how to create that user?

I already did this:

```
aws iam create-login-profile --user-name VeryAdmin --password verypassword
aws iam add-user-to-group --user-name VeryAdmin --group admin
```

And successfully logged in to console, but still has no access to changing the number. The article in documentation said that the user should have access to this:

```
The IAM user enabled on the AWS account has administrator access permission.
The IAM user has access to the AWS Billing console.
```

No idea how to correctly add them via CLI

Comment: "The article in documentation" - which documentation? Can you provide link and exact quote which you are referring to?

Comment: This won’t be possible. The only way to change your phone number is by logging in through root credentials and enabling billing access for your IAM users. If you don’t have Billing Console access enabled for IAM users, you’re out of luck. You’ll probably need some legalized proof of identify from a notary.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to change any details belonging to your account you will need to be logged in as root user:

*Change your account settings. This includes the account name, email address, root user password, and root user access keys. Other account settings, such as contact information, payment currency preference, and AWS Regions, don't require root user credentials*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/accounts/latest/reference/root-user-tasks.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html

Comment: Actually, I changed my phone number via CLI and restored my access in a blink of an eye .__.